# merge two results to one table

Tags: sql, postgresql

If I have

```
SELECT count(id) FROM students;

count
---------
123

SELECT count(id) FROM staff;

count
---------
456
```

I want it to be like following

```
nstu  | nsta
--------------
123   | 456
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Tag the RDBMS you are using as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use subquery

```
SELECT * FROM  
    (SELECT count(id) FROM students) as nstu ,
    (SELECT count(id) FROM staff) nsta;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT (SELECT count(id) FROM students) as nstu ,(SELECT count(id) FROM staff) nsta;
```

For Oracle

```
SELECT (SELECT count(id) FROM students) as nstu ,
       (SELECT count(id) FROM staff) nsta 
FROM Dual;
```

Comment: Can I have the method for PostgreSQL, sorry for not specific in the tag

Answer (score 1):

```
Select
(SELECT count(id) FROM students) c1,
(SELECT count(id) FROM staff) c2
from dual;
```

Comment: Does Postgresql have the dual table?

Answer (score 1):

Do a `cross join`:

```
select s1.nstu, s2.nsta
from
(SELECT count(*) as nstu FROM students) s1
cross join
(SELECT count(*) as nsta FROM staff) s2
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach using union instead of subquery (MSSQL)

```
SELECT SUM(Students) AS 'Students' ,SUM(Staff) AS 'Staff'
FROM
(
    SELECT 'Student' AS 'Type', count(id) AS 'Students',0 AS 'Staff' FROM students
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Staff' AS 'Type', 0 AS 'Students',count(id) AS 'Staff' FROM staff
) AS Subset
```